# ASP.Net ajaxToolkit:InsertOrderedList does not work

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have using AJAX HtmlEditorExtender in my project. All the control of this editor working properly, but InsertOrderedList is not working. if anybody having solution, please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: show your code that you tried

Comment: don't do it in comment ,ad it in Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <div style=" color: black;">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtProjectsDetails" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="200" MaxLength="2000" />
                                        <asp:HtmlEditorExtender ID="txtHtmlEditorExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtProjectsDetails" DisplaySourceTab="false" EnableSanitization="false"></asp:HtmlEditorExtender>
                                    </div>
```